# How to extract browser cookie(s) using Katalon Studio

Tags: cookies, katalon-studio

I am trying to get all the cookies of the browser which is opened while we execute automation test using Katalon.

Please suggest how we can extract a specific cookie/list of cookies using Katalon.

I have checked in traditional Selenium/Java; its pretty easy -

```
driver.manage().getCookieNamed("Cookie Name").getValue();
```

But I am not getting any clue how to do this in Katalon.

Comment: It would be better if you wrote your answer as an answer and not as a comment so other people will get to see it and vote on it.

Comment: @MateMrše - Done that.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved it....

```
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.driver.DriverFactory 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver 

WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver() println driver.manage().getCookieNamed("Cookie Name").getValue()
```