# How to fetch(get) Cookie value, Server name and Other Header details for web application in Katalon Studio without API testing

Tags: testing, cookies, automation, katalon-studio, katacoda

please help for implement and how to test that verify following in Katalon studio

1. Request response has a header Server: <>
2. Request response has a header X-cache-status: <>
3. Request response has a cookie with name (get all cookie name )
4. Request response cookie value is unique for each visitor.

[please see my attach image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DATYr.png)
please any solution then give your ans .. 
Thank You

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you tried anything yourself, so we can start there?

Comment: i have to implement script in Katalon studio but error is generate like ,1. https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-handle-cookies-in-selenium-webdriver  2. https://artoftesting.com/handling-cookies-in-selenium-webdriver 3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54899900/how-to-extract-browser-cookies-using-katalon-studio  but this all not work for Katalon studio  . please provide solution as soon as possible  for  my all question

Comment: Did you searched solution online? What you already found?

Comment: yes i have to search online but solution not get for katalon studio..

Comment: when i search my question related ans then only displayed API testing but my question is  without API testing how to i will fetch Header details for web site

Comment: please sir see my attachment so more idea for my question..